# How do I check if a user has one role exactly in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

Suppose in my system there are four user roles-

```
1. ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
2. ROLE_ADMIN
3. ROLE_EDITOR
4. ROLE_AUTHOR
```

Now think, a user has role ROLE_AUTHOR. He can access a specific document but none other user can  access it. So I want permit only user who has `ROLE_AUTHOR`. I got some solution when searching which has like
`is_granted('ROLE_AUTHOR')` but this return a hierarchical result. Because in my config file I set hierarchy.
So how can I give permission only `ROLE_AUTHOR` user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check the user has the role exactly.

***In twig:***

```
{% if 'ROLE_AUTHOR' in app.user.roles %}
...
{% endif %}
```

***In controller:***

```
if (in_array('ROLE_AUTHOR', $this->getUser()->getRoles(), true)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are probably storing the user role in your user entity so you should just have to call the getter for the your roles field (ie: getRoles()) and check that.

Answer (score 0):

Note the accepted answer here doesn't take into account role hierarchy. It only checks for specific roles that are assigned, not roles which might be inherited by configuration.

The following is the best code to use (for controllers).

```
if($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
{
    // your code
}
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles